# How to processed with this problem?

Tags: probability

> Given $n$ biased coin with the $m$-th  coin having probability of throwing head equal to $\dfrac{1}{2m+1}$ $(m=1,2,3,4,5\dots n)$ are tossed once. The probability of getting odd number of head, if the result for each coin is independent, is $\dfrac{αn}{βn+γ}$. Then what is $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ equal to?

My approach: Probability of getting odd number of head = p(getting $1$ head)+p(probability of getting $3$ head)$\dots$+p(probability of getting $n^{th}$ head)

$$\frac13+\frac17+\frac1{11}+\cdots+\frac1{2n+1} \text{ (if n is odd)}\\
\frac13+\frac17+\frac1{11}+\cdots+\frac1{2n-1} \text{ (if n is even)}$$

The series above is harmonic so I did not get the result of the form $\dfrac{\alpha n}{\beta n+\gamma}$.

Comment: Since the series tends to $\infty,$ when $n$ is large your formula gives a probability greater than $1,$ so it must be incorrect.

Comment: @saulspatz how probability greater than 1 if n tend to ∞.

Comment: How indeed.  He is trying to point out to you that you should not be adding these probabilities together like that...

Comment: What I'm saying is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{4n+1}}=\infty.$  Surely you know this.  Therefore, your formula must be wrong.

Comment: @saulspatz Got you

Comment: As an aside, the expression $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+\dots$ that you tried to write above was actually $Pr(\text{head on first flip})+Pr(\text{head on third flip})+Pr(\text{head on fifth flip})+\dots$ which is not what you intended to calculate at all.  The result of the summation that you calculated is instead the expected number of heads to have been flipped on an odd-numbered flip.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

You should be able to tell that when $n=1$ the probability of an odd number of heads will be $\frac{1}{3}$ and the probability of an even number of heads will be $\frac{2}{3}$.

Now... for $n=2$ you will have an odd number of heads with probability $\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{4}{5}+\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{5}$ and you will have an even number of heads with probability $\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{4}{5}+\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{5}$.  Make sure you stop and fully understand why.

Now... let us define a function $f$ such that $f(n)$ is the probability of flipping an odd number of heads in $n$ flips.

We then notice that $f(n)$ can be defined recursively and that $f(n+1)=f(n)\times\frac{2(n+1)}{2(n+1)+1}+(1-f(n))\times\frac{1}{2(n+1)+1}$.  Again.  Stop and make sure you understand exactly why.

Now... armed with this information, try and continue towards a closed form.

Comment: When n=1, how can you get " even number of heads "?

Comment: @AaryanDewan By having flipped zero heads and one tail. For some reason some people forget that zero is an even number.